# How to use Sinon on mocha to mock input type="file" for AJAX testing

Tags: html, unit-testing, file-upload, mocha.js, sinon

I got a unit test on Mocha, and I'm testing form submission through AJAX.

Since you can't fill the `<input type="file">` manually, and I'm looking for automated tests, I need to know whats the best way to "mock" this input, and still be able to send it through AJAX in the multipart format (can be a plain text "file" like, with Hello world!).

I know I can just craft the string manually, but I need to "replace" the `<input type="file">` value in the object with my mock (that can still respond to my mocked `FormData` object)

Comment: I was going to provide an answer to this but since my answer doesn't help much I'm going to place it as a comment. It sounds like you already have a mocked FormData object and you just want to swap the input type="file" with it. You won't be able to do that iirc. Why don't you just submit the formData object? I guess that would mean you'd be testing more than you want (like your ability to mimic your form entirely), but i think that is the only option. Let us know what you find out!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test binary file upload with mocha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249288/test-binary-file-upload-with-mocha)

Comment: Mocking an input field sounds like a lot of unecessary work to me. Whether the input works or not is up to the browser's dev team, not the web developer. Only test code you write and make sure that it does whatever you expect it to do using tests.