# Test binary file upload with mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, restify

I'm currently working on a small API with nodejs and restify that requires a file upload done, by receiving a binary string.

What I dont know how to do, is test it with mocha, so Ive been doing some search and found this on stack overflow [Unit test file upload with mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120866/how-to-unit-test-with-a-file-upload-in-mocha), its a fine start but it wont work because its sending a multipart form, and what I require the client to send on the api is the file as a stream.

Heres my controller:

```
exports.uploadVideo = function(req, res, next) {
    var video = "public/video/" + req.params.videoId + ".mp4",
        util  = require('util'),
        exec = require('child_process').exec;

    var newFile = fs.createWriteStream("./uploads/" + video);

    req.pipe(newFile);

    req.on('end', function () {
        var cmd = 'qtfaststart ' + './uploads/' + video;
        var qtfaststart = exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr){
            if (error === "atom not found, is this a valid MOV/MP4 file?\n" || error !== null) {
                return next(new restify.ConflictError("Error: " + stdout));
            } else {
                fs.chmodSync('./uploads/' + video, '644');
                Video.findOne( { _id: req.params.videoId }, function(err, video) {
                    if (err) return next(new restify.ConflictError(err));
                    if (!video) {
                        newVideo = new Video({
                            _id: req.params.videoId,
                            file: video});
                        newVideo.save()

                    } else {
                        video.file = video;
                        video.increment();
                        video.save();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(err){
        return next(new restify.NetworkConnectTimeoutError(err));
    });
};
```

So given this controller which receives a stream (binary file), and puts the stream together on the backend, how would I test this controller with mocha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `http` for that:

```
it('should be possible to upload a file', function(done) {
  var http        = require('http');
  var options     = require('url').parse(YOUR_URL);
  options.method  = 'POST';

  var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
    // TODO: check for errors, correct response, etc...
    done(...);
  });

  require('fs').createReadStream(YOUR_TEST_FILE).pipe(req);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module from within mocha. It supports multi-part forms.